# Trying to save a value within an if statement an reuse it later

Tags: pine-script

I would like to:

1. save my entry price in the variable `lowEntery`.
2. calculate a target price to the variable `exitShort` for my short 0.5 % lower the entry price
3. Use `exitShort` as trigger to close my short

```
    if (strategy.position_size >= 0)
        if (close < close[1])
            strategy.entry(id="EnterShort", long=false)
            lowEntery = close

    exitShort = lowEntery *0.005 

    strategy.close(id="EnterShort", when = close<= exitShort)
```

I get
Undeclared identifier 'lowEntery';
Undeclared identifier 'exitShort'

I dont understand why 'lowEntery' is considered undeclared

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Quick answer

```
entryPrice = valuewhen(strategy.position_size[0] > strategy.position_size[1], open, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Local variables *(variables within a loop or if statement)* that are used outside a local scope need to be declared beforehand, in your case you want to declare `lowEntery` before your `if` statement.

```
lowEntery = 0.
if (strategy.position_size >= 0)
    if (close < close[1])
        strategy.entry(id="EnterShort", long=false)
        lowEntery := close

exitShort = lowEntery *0.005 
strategy.close(id="EnterShort", when = close<= exitShort)
```

EDIT

In your case I believe you want to use something like that instead

```
lowEntery = 0.
if strategy.position_size >= 0 and close > close[1]
    strategy.entry(id="EnterShort", long=false)
    lowEntery := close
else
    lowEntery := lowEntery[1]

exitShort = lowEntery*0.005
strategy.close(id="EnterShort", when = close<= exitShort)
```

in the precedent case `lowEntery` won't hold a value, that's why you use `else`, you should get more trades that way, altho I had to use values such as 0.9 or 0.9999 instead of 0.005 to get more trades, hope that helps.

Comment: the errors are gone. Thanks. But now i am just entering a firsttrade but never exiting it. feels like lowEntery = 0 -> exitShort  = 0 and therefore trade wont be closed as long as close is not <= 0. Any idea?

Comment: I changed the example a bit:
   if (strategy.position_size >= 0)
       if (close == 9800)
        strategy.entry(id="EnterShort", long=false)
        lowEntery := close

   exitShort = lowEntery *0.005 

   strategy.close(id="EnterShort", when = close<= exitShort)


Even this trade is never closed with btc pair in 1 h for example, but it should if i am not wrong.

Comment: I think I know what you want to do, I will edit my answer

Comment: thanks it works now. but i dont understand why :-( 
why does it makes a difference to add the following code
"else
    lowEntery := lowEntery[1]"

Because i thought this lines are just executed when the trade is in active position or <>9800 - this should not make difference to save the value of close once the condition "strategy.position_size >= 0 and close > close[1]" is meet?
I guess i am not understanding something basic here. Can you enlight me?